# UrlfetchApp catch exceptions

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**I want to catch the exceptions, If the request was failed it will output value in to status "Failed" else "Completed". I've tried object.length but it doesn't return anything. Please help. Thanks**

```
function sendRequest()
{
var dataRequestPost = {
    "amount": amount,
    "email": {
    "recipient_email": email,
    "subject": esubject,
    "message": emessage
},
    "ref": {
    "order_id": "string",
    "email": email,
    "id1": "string",
    "id2": "string",
    "phone_number": snumber
},
  "add_to_blacklist": false
      
};
var rUrl = encodeURI('https://data.seller.tools/api/v1/USD');
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(rUrl, {
    "method": "post",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    },
    "payload": JSON.stringify(dataRequestPost)
});
var object = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
Logger.log(object);
  
if(object.length > 0)
{
  sheet.getRange(row,6).setValue("Completed");
}
else
{
  sheet.getRange(row,6).setValue("Failed");
}
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the getContentText(), use getResponseCode().

**Example Response Code:**

> **200 OK**
>
> - The request has succeeded. The meaning of the success depends on the HTTP method:
> - GET: The resource has been fetched and is transmitted in the message body.
> - HEAD: The entity headers are in the message body.
> - PUT or POST: The resource describing the result of the action is transmitted in the message body.
> - TRACE: The message body contains the request message as received by the server.
>
> **404 Not Found**
>
> - The server can not find the requested resource. In the browser, this means the URL is not recognized. In an API, this can also mean
>   that the endpoint is valid but the resource itself does not exist.
>   Servers may also send this response instead of 403 to hide the
>   existence of a resource from an unauthorized client. This response
>   code is probably the most famous one due to its frequent occurrence on
>   the web.

### Example:

**Code:**

```
function sendRequest() {
  var query = '"Apps Script" stars:">=100"';
  var url = 'https://api.github.com/seach/repositories'
    + '?sort=stars'
    + '&q=' + encodeURIComponent(query);

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {'muteHttpExceptions': true});
  var responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if(responseCode == 200){
    sh.getRange(1,1).setValue("Completed");
  }else{
    sh.getRange(1,1).setValue("Failed");
  }
}
```

**Output if response code is 200:**

[image: Completed]

**Others:**

[image: Failed]

### References:

- [HTTP response status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)
- [getResponseCode()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getresponsecode)